# SimpleModal 1.3.2 Contact Form Not Sending

Tags: simplemodal

I just downloaded the SimpleModal 1.3.2 Contact Form to my localhost to try it out; the only change I've made is to the user settings in data/contact.php. I get the thankyou message and SimpleModal closes after I hit "send". However, something prevents the email from being sent; I never receive it in my inbox. Any comments would be welcome; it's a slick system and I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, that means that the problem is on the server end. You can uncomment the @ in front of @mail (data/contact.php) to see if you get a server error back. If not, it means there is a problem on the system with mail delivery.

Let me know what you find out.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was very simple, I just had to modify the post url path in contact.js, line 117.

Thank you very much for such a beautiful and functional contact form,

Best